# Conditional query in the select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, conditional-statements

I am exposing my concern to you.

There are "demande_psy" and "consultant" tables. Each "demande_psy" record can relate to several "consultants" records, and each "consultant" record can relate to several "demande_psy" records, according to a "statut". This is the reason why, the primary key of the "demande_psy_consultant" link table (many to many relation table) is composed of: "id_demande_psy", "id_consultant", "statut". By querying the database , I need to retrieve a list of demande_psy and their priority statut, according to these 3 rules:

- If among the same demand_psy, I have at least one AFFECTED status => my request line must display the "Affected" status
- Otherwise, if among the same demande_psy, I have at least one status ACCEPTED => my demande_psy line must display "Accepted"
- Otherwise my demande_psy line should show "Sent"

Here my tables creation code :

```
CREATE TABLE `demande_psy` (
`id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`titre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`detail` text NOT NULL,
`sms` text NOT NULL,
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
`modified_at` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `demande_psy` (`id`, `titre`, `detail`, `sms`, `created_at`) 
VALUES (1, 'Test demande', 'bla bla bla bla', 'qsdf\r\nqsdf\r\n', '2021-03-18 17:23:59');
ALTER TABLE `demande_psy` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `demande_psy` MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;

CREATE TABLE `consultant` (
`id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`prenom` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`nom` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `consultant` (`id`, `prenom`, `nom`) VALUES 
(52, 'Michel', 'Moral (Somica - Undici)'),
(55, 'Patrick', 'Amar');
ALTER TABLE `consultant` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`); 
ALTER TABLE `consultant`  MODIFY `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL     AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=56;

CREATE TABLE `demande_psy_consultant` (
`id_demande_psy` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`id_consultant` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`statut` enum('SENT','ACCEPTED','AFFECTED') NOT NULL,
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `demande_psy_consultant` (`id_demande_psy`, `id_consultant`, 
`statut`, `created_at`) VALUES
(1, 52, 'SENT', '2021-03-18 17:39:59'),
(1, 55, 'ACCEPTED', '2021-03-18 19:05:45');
ALTER TABLE `demande_psy_consultant` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_demande_psy`,`id_consultant`,`statut`);
ALTER TABLE `demande_psy_consultant`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_consultant` FOREIGN KEY (`id_consultant`) REFERENCES `consultant` (`id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_demande_psy` FOREIGN KEY (`id_demande_psy`) REFERENCES `demande_psy` (`id`);
```

Here a simplified example :

```
demande_psy
-----------
1    toto
6    titi

consultant
----------
15   Marc
88   Jean

demande_psy_consultant
----------------------
1    15    SENT 
1    62    SENT 
1    88    ACCEPTED
1    88    AFFECTED
6    88    SENT 
6    15    SENT

==> EXPECTED RESULT
---------------------------------------------------
1    88   AFFECTED (according to the 3 rules)
6    15   SENT
```

And now, here is my sql query:

```
SELECT 
DPC.id_demande_psy, 
DPC.id_consultant,
(CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT count(DPC.statut) FROM demande_psy_consultant DPC WHERE DPC.statut = "AFFECTED")>0 THEN "AFFECTED"
    WHEN (SELECT count(DPC.statut) FROM demande_psy_consultant DPC WHERE DPC.statut = "ACCEPTED")>0 THEN "ACCEPTED"
    ELSE "SENT"
 END) as statutComputed
 FROM demande_psy_consultant DPC
 GROUP BY DPC.id_demande_psy
```

With it, I obtain :

```
MY (BAD) RESULT
---------------
1    15   AFFECTED
6    15   AFFECTED
```

So I struggle a bit to correct it to obtain the desired result If anyone has an idea, I'm interested

thank you !

Comment: Ah, a "request" is a "database query". Can you explain what the data in these 3 tables, and the 3 statuses, represent? It's so much easier to understand what you try to achieve if it is known what this is about.

Comment: Thanks @KIKOSoftware. I edited my first question a bit more understanding.

Comment: The values you insert into the tables in the SQL code do not match your _simplified example_. You insert `Patrick` into table `consultant` but _Patrick_ doesn't appear in your example. For me, that makes it hard to reproduce your problem. Similarly, _Marc_ appears in your example but you don't insert _Marc_ in the SQL.